# Is it possible to create a new Windows Server Role?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to create new Windows Server Roles (much like IIS, DNS, DHCP, AD, AD CS and so on)?

I don't have a specific product or system I want to make, but I often wonder when I see the server manager dashboards of Server2012+, if it's possible to get the same management for own roles.

An example could be if I created a new product, that I published the installer somewhere and had it installed (via. the add/remove roles wizard) on one or more servers. I could then manage this new product using the server manager (and associated MMC snap-ins), in addition to viewing the roles status on the dashboard.

The role could expose stuff like: is the service running, what are the recent event logs, open manager window etc.

I just can't seem to find any mention of it anywhere.

Comment: The answer is no, but that is a neat idea that I've never thought about before.

Comment: In my opinion, it would make great sense for many applications running on one or more Windows servers.. Especially with Server Nano coming out, where remote administration becomes even more important.... I've just never seen an SDK to interface with it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you're limited to what Windows offers for roles and features. The other things you're talking about will need program(s) to accomplish.

For managing a product like that, you would have to do it manually I would think. That and I'm not sure a Windows role or feature would be the best idea. You would need monitoring and functionality, that sounds like something specific would have to be set in place.

Comment: Marked this as the answer, as no-one have chipped in with a "Yes".

Answer (score 0):

You would not be able to plug a third party role into Windows Server Manager. I would imagine you would have to create your own front-end management seperately